# How to get hash code of static object C#?

Tags: c#, .net, static

I am a begginer .NET developer. I am trying to understand basic things to better understand of what's really going in my code.

Is it possible to get a hashcode of a static object? And might it be necessary in any cases?

The code is below:

```
class DynamicClass
{
 //Class body
}


static class StaticClass
{
  //Class body
}

class program 
{
   static void Main()
   { 
     //Getting hashcode of DynamicClass object
     DynamicClass x = new DynamicClass();
     Console.WriteLine(x.GetHashCode());

    //Getting hashcode of StaticClass object
    //Since the class is static i can't instantiate it, so i am
    //trying to call GetHashCode method right on the object
    Console.WriteLine(StaticClass.GetHashCode()); // ERROR CS120 

   }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: There is no situation in which you would need to search for a static class. You cannot put classes in dictionaries or instances, just instances of classes could be in a dictionary. Classes are Types, and for  a dictionary of Types see Iv's answer.

Comment: @Holder Thank you very much! That's what i was thinking. Since it doesn't have any instances we don't need any hashcodes from it

Comment: @AntonGogolev, i am just playing with the code digging for more clear understanding. I was stuck when i tried to get a hashcode for a static class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get type and call GetHashCode on it instead. Example:

```cs
typeof(StaticClass).GetHashCode()
```

Source: [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gethashcode)

Comment: There is no way to obtain a "hash code of a static class" because the concept doesn't make sense. What you've done is obtain the hash code of the Type object for the static class. It may be enough for whatever OP wanted to use the hash code for, but it is not actually the hash code of the static class.